# Finding the Datediff between Records in same Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
IP             QID  ScanDate                Rank
101.110.32.80   6   2016-09-28 18:33:21.000 3
101.110.32.80   6   2016-08-28 18:33:21.000 2
101.110.32.80   6   2016-05-30 00:30:33.000 1
```

I have a Table with certain records, grouped by Ipaddress and QID.. My requirement is to find out which record missed the sequence in the date column or other words the date difference is more than 30 days. In the above table date diff between rank 1 and rank 2 is more than 30 days.So, i should flag the rank 2 record.

Comment: please show expected result and also tag the version of SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use windowed function to avoid self join which in many case will perform better.

```
WITH    cte
          AS (
              SELECT
                t.IP
              , t.QID
              , LAG(t.ScanDate) OVER (PARTITION BY t.IP ORDER BY T.ScanDate) AS beginScanDate
              , t.ScanDate AS endScanDate
              , DATEDIFF(DAY,
                         LAG(t.ScanDate) OVER (PARTITION BY t.IP ORDER BY t.ScanDate),
                         t.ScanDate) AS Diff
              FROM
                MyTable AS t
             )
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        cte c
    WHERE
        Diff > 30;
```

Answer (score 1):

While [Window Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) could be used here, I think a self join might be more straight forward and easier to understand:

```
SELECT
t1.IP,
    t1.QID,
    t1.Rank,
    t1.ScanDate as endScanDate,
    t2.ScanDate as beginScanDate,
    datediff(day, t2.scandate, t1.scandate) as scanDateDays     
FROM
    table as t1
    INNER JOIN table as t2 ON
        t1.ip = t2.ip
        t1.rank - 1 = t2.rank --get the record from t2 and is one less in rank
WHERE datediff(day, t2.scandate, t1.scandate) > 30 --only records greater than 30 days
```

It's pretty self-explanatory. We are joining the table to itself and joining the ranks together where rank 2 gets joined to rank 1, rank 3 gets joined to rank 2, and so on. Then we just test for records that are greater than 30 days using the datediff function.

Comment: I'm not sure why the 'rank' is relevant here

Comment: An approach that doesn't take into account rank would show both rank tuples (1,2) and (1,3) as being flagged. Since op doesn't call out rank tuple (1,3) I made the assumption that OP only cares about the date ranges between consecutive ranks. Since the joins then are well defined, and given that OP didn't discover any solution to their problem even though there are multiple, I decided that a self join using consecutive ranks to establish a relationship would be a good option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LAG` in Sql 2012+

```
declare @Tbl Table (Ip VARCHAR(50), QID INT, ScanDate DATETIME,[Rank] INT)

INSERT INTO @Tbl        
VALUES  
('101.110.32.80', 6,   '2016-09-28 18:33:21.000', 3),
('101.110.32.80', 6,   '2016-08-28 18:33:21.000', 2),
('101.110.32.80', 6,   '2016-05-30 00:30:33.000', 1)

;WITH Result
AS
(
    SELECT
        T.Ip ,
        T.QID ,
        T.ScanDate ,
        T.[Rank],
        LAG(T.[Rank]) OVER (ORDER BY T.[Rank]) PrivSRank,
        LAG(T.ScanDate) OVER (ORDER BY T.[Rank]) PrivScanDate
    FROM
        @Tbl T
) 

SELECT
    R.Ip ,
    R.QID ,
    R.ScanDate ,
    R.Rank ,
    R.PrivScanDate,
    IIF(DATEDIFF(DAY, R.PrivScanDate, R.ScanDate) > 30, 'This is greater than 30 day. Rank ' + CAST(R.PrivSRank AS VARCHAR(10)), '') CFlag
FROM
    Result R
```

Result:

```
Ip                       QID         ScanDate                Rank        CFlag
------------------------ ----------- ----------------------- ----------- --------------------------------------------
101.110.32.80            6           2016-05-30 00:30:33.000 1           
101.110.32.80            6           2016-08-28 18:33:21.000 2           This is greater than 30 day. Rank 1
101.110.32.80            6           2016-09-28 18:33:21.000 3           This is greater than 30 day. Rank 2
```